# Migrate home-brew back from M1 to Intel

Tags: macos, homebrew, apple-m1

I needed to migrate back from a M1 MacBook to an Intel one again. Yes I do not like it either but that is my challenge. I used build in the Migration Assistant from Apple to copy over all relevant files and settings. Home-brew folder exists on contains the old M1 installation.

Now every time I try to do anything I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot install on Intel processor in ARM default prefix (/opt/homebrew)! 
Error: 'git' must be installed and in your PATH!
```

Trying to install git also does not work:

```
xxxxx@xxxxx:~$ brew install git
git 2.33.1 is already installed but outdated
Error: Cannot install on Intel processor in ARM default prefix (/opt/homebrew)!
Error: 'git' must be installed and in your PATH!
git 2.33.1 is already installed but outdated
Error: Cannot install on Intel processor in ARM default prefix (/opt/homebrew)!
```

`brew doctor` also didn't help.

Comment: What does that mean, "migrate back"? Are you restoring a Time Machine backup or something?

Comment: Thanks for the question. I updated to original question above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you still have access to the M1 Mac:

1. On the M1 Mac, run `brew bundle dump` and copy the resulting `Brewfile` to your Intel Mac
2. On the Intel Mac

   - Remove `/opt/homebrew`
   - Install brew using the instructions on brew.sh
   - Run `brew bundle install --file /path/to/Brewfile` to reinstall packages

If you don't have access to your M1 Mac any longer, run `ls /opt/homebrew/Cellar` on the new Mac to get a list of installed packages, followed by step 2.1 and 2.2 from above. Then manually install the packages again.